# How to set alignment for virtual functions?

Tags: c++, com, mingw, vtable

I'm developing plug-in for Win32 using mingw and crosscompilation from linux. Although my plugin successfuly loaded by application and I even got an com-interface from app, I cant call functions from there - app is crashed. I think that this is due to wrong vtable alignment of interface implementation in mingw (this worked perfectly with MSVS).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VTable alignment (in fact, the entire VTable system at all) is completely implementation dependent. You have to use the same compiler, compiled with the same switches/settings, in order to have a workable program after linkage.

You can't link msvc generated binaries against MinGW generated ones for this reason. Even if you got the tables to align the same, the name mangling algorithms are different, and nobody says that the two compilers would choose the same order for the individual functions within the vtable itself.

If you need a portable interface between the two compilers, then you have to do it with a C (technically an `extern "C"`) interface, which has a standardized ABI.

Comment: COM is also an ABI, but maybe one which MinGW does not support so easily. :) (COM is based on the (not quite true!) assumption that all C++ compilers on a given platform will use the same vtable structure and layout. I'm surprised that MinGW makes it so difficult as COM is a major part of Win32. Other C++ compilers support COM fine, though, so you don't need to use C or the same compiler; just a decent C++ compiler for Windows.) Of course, you can also do COM in straight C (the code generated by the IDL compiler typically defines a C interface as well) if it's easier.